# Android place TextView depends on its center

Tags: android, textview

How to place TextViews on layout depends on TextView's center from code?By default we can create it depends on its top left angle. Method setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL) doesn't help.

EDIT

I want to place TextViews in circle. For what I use RelativeLayout. Within layot TextViews place in for-loop with some angle step. Here some code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 62; i++) {
        TextView word = new TextView(context);
        word.setTextSize(13);
        // word.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        word.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0,
                angle.get(i), 0, (float) (textHeight * 0.9 + rotateCircle));
        rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        rotateAnimation.setDuration(100);
        rotateAnimation.setStartOffset(100);

        word.setAnimation(rotateAnimation);
        word.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        word.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutparams.leftMargin = Math.round(x_coords.get(i));

        layoutparams.topMargin = (int) (Math.round(y_coords.get(i)
                - textHeight * 0.9 - rotateCircle));
        textviews.add(word);

        words_layout.addView(word, layoutparams);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The *gravity* of a `TextView` controls how its content is aligned *(the text)*, not how the view itself is aligned in the *layout*. To control how the `View` is aligned in the *layout* use the `android::layout_gravity` attribute instead, or the `gravity` field in the `LayoutParams`.

Comment: @vovaxo: Yes, it does work. Maybe it doesn't work in your particular use case because you are doing something else wrong, but then again we don't know what your particular use case is. Add some context please, layouts, sources, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use the **android:layout_gravity = CENTER_HORIZONTAL** to make text view in center.

Comment: I don't create TextView in xml to use android:layout_gravity